# input Textboxes over an image

Tags: html, css, image

How can I place textboxes over an image, and anchor the textboxes 
fix on the image.

When I resize the image anchoring is lost.

the textbox should be scaled proportionally to the image

```css
body, html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }


/* Container holding the image and the text */
.bg_img {
    /* Control the height of the image */
   height: 1500px;  
   background-repeat: no-repeat;   
   position: relative;
  }  

.innerContainer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px; 
    width: 100%;  
    height: 100%;
}

/* Full-width input fields */
input[type=text], input[type=password] {    
    position: absolute;
    border: none;
    background: #f1f1f1;
}

input[type=text]:focus, input[type=password]:focus {
    background-color: #ddd;
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="myContainer">
        <div class="bg_img" style="background-image: url(img/Aufm.jpg)">        
            <div class="innerContainer">
                <input type="text" placeholder="h" name="l1" style="left: 20px; top: 320px; width: 80px; transform: rotate(90deg);">
                <input type="text" placeholder="b" name="l1" style="left: 20px; top: 220px; width: 80px; transform: rotate(90deg);">
                <input type="text" placeholder="h2" name="l1" style="left: 300px; top: 320px; width: 80px;">
            </div>        
          </div>
      </div>
```

[image: input on image]

The images size are different.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

your inline style has left and right pixel that's why it's  make a scrollbar you can try to use % instance of px.
hope you solve your problem, if not let me know details